# Set up tests with Typescript and Ava : bad require

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, ava

I'm setting up AVA with Typescript to tests my JS code. Internally, I'm first calling TSC to compile my files, then call AVA with babel-register to test them (Babel register allowing require to be resolved).

```
"ava": "tsc && ava testJs/**/*.spec.js"
```

testJs being the output folder of Ts. My problem is that, even thought everything pretty much work, I have this kind of statement, usually picked up by Webpack :

```
import "./index.page.css";
```

Webpack gently require it, but babel-register doesn't. I had to change the behavior to accept .css file as noop. Here is the issue : because I'm using tsc as a compiler, those files are not copied at all in testJs, meaning they are not available in the first place.

I wanted to know what would be the best way to solve this, as I think copy-pasting the whole folder (to have all files available) just to execute tests is a bit of an overkill. Especially since, if I suddenly import a .json file  (for example)I will have new problems.

For example, is there a way to tell babel-register to ignore require it cant resolve instead of breaking ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ignore-styles](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles) to ignore certain types of requires. By default it ignores all kinds of CSS and images ([full list](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles/blob/master/ignore-styles.js#L1-L18)) and you can customise it to ignore other extensions as well.

You simply require it before `babel-register` in your AVA config.